# Integrate kerberos and Keychain

Tags: mac, kerberos

It it possible to make `kinit` ask Keychain for password and not me?

Answer (score 29):

`kinit` on Mac OS X now (since 10.9, possibly earlier) has built-in support for saving the password to the keychain via the `--keychain` argument, accomplishing the same thing as paul's answer.

Authenticate using `kinit --keychain`; the password will be saved upon successful authentication:

```
kinit --keychain
# or
kinit --keychain bob@MY.REAL.COM
```

Subsequent `kinit` invocations (which don't require the `--keychain` argument) will automatically get the saved password from your keychain instead of prompting you to enter it.

Comment: Wow an option not even mentioned on the `kinit` man page, and works well. Nice.

Comment: Note that macports' kerberos package may not have the --keychain option available...and is the first on the PATH if installed, but the built-in one does :) `kinit: unrecognized option --keychain'`

Answer (score 15):

Actually it is possible. Let us say you have an account "bob" on the realm "MY.REAL.COM" with password "mypasswd". Then in a Terminal type on one single line

`security add-generic-password -a "bob" -l "MY.REAL.COM (bob)" -s "MY.REALM.COM" -w "mypasswd" -c "aapl" -T "/usr/bin/kinit"`

This will create an item in your default Keychain named "MY.REALM.COM (bob)" with your Kerberos credentials and kinit it will be authorized to access it. You can add as many `-T "/fulpath/program"` switches as you want, each will give access to the specific program to use your kerberos credentials. For example `-T "/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail"` will add access for Mail.app.

More details with `man security`.

After that `kinit bob@MY.REAL.COM` will not prompt you for a password but will get it from the keychain.

Comment: That is flippin' rad!

Comment: I couldn't make this work, however this does work with [Miles answer](https://superuser.com/a/950769/115951)

Answer (score -2):

With only kinit, this is impossible.

You'd have to write or have someone else write a separate interface that uses the Keychain Services API to store and access your passwords.

Comment: I just don't understand why Keychain is integrated so it remembers passphrase for ssh key, but can't remember password for kerberos.

Comment: It's because no one bothered to program it.